# Reactphp with symfony images and css

Tags: symfony, reactphp

I am using reactphp with symfony my react webserver link is http://localserver.reactsymfony:1337/.

none of css and images file serve. for example ( http://localserver.reactsymfony:1337/bundles/calibration/css/bootstrap.min.css ) it gives me 404 not found error.

I am clue less how I get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve these files yourself with ReactPHP or instead run a separate file server on a different port. You might be able to find some component that does exactly that, but I don't know of any.

By default, ReactPHP doesn't have any concept of a document root. It just has a request event handler and that's it.